# JavaScript ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a webpage to display some images and when clicked with pop-up a modal with thumbnail images at the bottom. I referenced w3Schools to create this and modified it a bit but now recieve a ReferenceError: currentImg is not defined in the console. When I click on an image the modal pops up but the image does not change when the arrows are clicked. Requesting help to understand the error and how to fix it. Please find below my code.

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showImgs(slideIndex);

function plusImg(n) {
  showImgs(slideIndex += n);
}

function plusImg(n) {
  showImgs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showImgs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length;
  }
  alert(x.length)
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    alert(i)
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-opacity-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-opacity-off";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```css
.s4 img {
  height: 413px;
  width: 319px;
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myModal span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.w3-content {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.w3-content .mySlides {
  width: 100%;
}

.w3-content .w3-col {
  padding: 5px;
}

.demo {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Commander, Carrier Strike Group ELEVEN (CCSG 11) Fact Sheet</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <div class="w3-row-padding">
      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <img src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page1.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentImg(1)" class="w3-hover-shadow">
        <img src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page2.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentImg(2)" class="w3-hover-shadow">
        <img src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page3.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentImg(3)" class="w3-hover-shadow">
        <img src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page4.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentImg(4)" class="w3-hover-shadow">
        <img src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page5.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentImg(5)" class="w3-hover-shadow">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="w3-modal w3-black" style="display: block;">
      <span class="w3-text-white w3-xxlarge w3-hover-text-grey w3-container w3-display-topright" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>

      <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-content">
          <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page1.jpg" style="display: block;">
          <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page2.jpg" style="display: none;">
          <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page3.jpg" style="display: none;">
          <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page4.jpg" style="display: none;">
          <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page5.jpg" style="display: none;">
          <div class="w3-row w3-black w3-center">
            <p id="caption">Page 1</p>
            <span class="w3-display-left w3-btn" onclick="plusImg(-1)">&lt;</span>
            <span class="w3-display-right w3-btn" onclick="plusImg(1)">&gt;</span>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s4">
            <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off w3-opacity-off" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page1.jpg" onclick="currentImg(1)" alt="Page 1">
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s4">
            <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page2.jpg" onclick="currentImg(2)" alt="Page 2">
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s4">
            <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page3.jpg" onclick="currentImg(3)" alt="Page 3">
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s4">
            <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page4.jpg" onclick="currentImg(4)" alt="Page 4">
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s4">
            <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/ccsg11/PublishingImages/FactSheet_Page5.jpg" onclick="currentImg(5)" alt="Page 5">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works here, `alert(x.length)` returns `5`. Or not?

Comment: There is no `currentImg` function into code that you've pasted, but you're calling it into `onclick` attribute for images. Do you ever have this function in code?

Comment: @Flying: Where would I put the function? I referenced this webpage and made a few modifications since I felt that they were unnecessary to what I wanted. https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_lightbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 functions with name plusImg.
Just rename second one to currentImg

```
function plusImg(n) {
  showImgs(slideIndex += n);
}

function plusImg(n) {
  showImgs(slideIndex = n);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the perfect solution and I must have glossed over it!

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your javascript codes:

1. there is missing function for currentImg

   ```
       function currentImg(n) {
         console.log(n);
         showImgs(n);
       }
   ```
2. there is duplicate plusImg function, please remove the 2nd one
3. there is error in showImgs function, please check my update js codes

   ```
       function openModal() {
         document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
       }

       function closeModal() {
         document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
       }

       var slideIndex = 1;
       showImgs(slideIndex);

       function plusImg(n) {
         showImgs(slideIndex += n);
       }

       function currentImg(n) {
         console.log(n);
         showImgs(n);
       }

       function showImgs(n) {
         var i;
         var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
         var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
         var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

         if (!x.length) return;

         slideIndex = n;
         if (n > x.length) {
           slideIndex = 1;
         }
         if (n < 1) {
           slideIndex = x.length;
         }
         console.log(x.length)
         for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           console.log(i)
           x[i].style.display = "none";
         }
         for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
           dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-opacity-off", "");
         }
         x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
         dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-opacity-off";
         captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
       }
   ```

BTW, I changed alert to console.log for better debug experience. I also added the style

```
.mySlides {display:none}
```

Please check. Hope above helps.